# Finding max element and it's index without using given functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the maximum number and it's index using only `for` loop and without any Python given function.

Here is my code:

```
def main():
    a = [2,1,5,9,8,3,7,4,6]
    max = 0
    index = 0

    for number in a:
        if number > max:
            max = number
    index += 1

    print(max, index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

After looping is finished I get correct max number, but incorrect index. What should I improve?

Comment: declare and use max_index variable

Comment: I am using max and index variables both.

Comment: I really wanna do this just because it seems interesting.. Give me a little bit

Comment: @13aal not really. It's a mundane homework assignment.

Comment: you need 2 indentation at the `index += 1`. I mean put it under the if statement because it will update the index only when the max is changed

Comment: @TanmayaMeher No, the index needs to change on every loop iteration. A separate variable is needed to store the index of the current max.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ well, I did it anyways, defiantly not as interesting as I thought it would be

Comment: @Tanmaya Meher  But, it will not give me exact index position of max number in list. Only number of max numbers before the biggest max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
a = [2,1,5,9,8,3,7,4,6]

# index: index of max, i: running index
max_index = -1  
i = 0
# do not shadow built-in 'max'
max_val = a[0] if a else None  # or sth. similar to handle negative or empty input

for number in a:
    if number > max_val:
        max_val = number
        max_index = i
    i += 1

print (max, max_index)
```

This assumes that all numbers in `a` are positive.

Comment: I guess it doesn't matter that we're shadowing `max` in this program. ;)

Comment: It should, you are right. Just staying close to the OP's nomenclature.

Comment: Shouldn't `max` be initialized to `-inf` or something similar? I'm worried that an all-negative list would give garbage data back

Comment: I guess we could initialize it to `min(a)` :D

Answer (score 5):

Move the `index` incrementation to the body of the loop and keep the index for the maximum number, e.g:

```
def main():
    a = [2, 1, 5, 9, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6]
    max_number = max_index = index = 0

    for number in a:
        if number > max_number:
            max_number = number
            max_index = index
        index += 1

    print(max_number, max_index)
```

Also, don't name your variable `max` to avoid shadowing the built-in [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) of the same name.

Answer (score -1):

You should indent the line 9 variable index inside the for loop.

```
def main():
    a = [2,1,5,9,8,3,7,4,6]
    max = 0
    index = 0

    for number in a:
        if number > max:
            max = number
            #index +=1 should happen here 
            index += 1
         #index previously here 

    print (max, index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: you should have indented `index += 1` in the if not in the for loop. Doing it in the for loop will loop in the whole list. Your attempt was almost a copy-paste of OP's code. ;)

Comment: I know it. I thought he want very similar code to his own, but working.

Comment: keep pushing, you will get more knowledgeable next time.

Answer (score -1):

This will probably do what you want it to do:

```
def find_max_index(data, max_num=0, index_of_max=0, step=1):
    for item in data:
        if int(item) > max_num:
            max_num = int(item)
            index_of_max += step
    return max_num, index_of_max - step
```

Here's an example:

```
items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 999, 6, 7, 8, 9]
find_max_index(items)
# (999, 4)
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Try with `items = [1, 2, 0, 0, 999]`